# To use shared_ptr, is it safe ?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have got some confused about shared_ptr.

Say, I have classes:

```
class foo {
     int _f;
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<foo> fooptr;

class bar {
    int _b;
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<bar> barptr;

class foobar : public foo, public bar {
    int _fb;
};

int main () {

    foobar *fb1 = new foobar();
    foobar *fb2 = new foobar();

    fooptr f((foo *)fb1);
    barptr b((bar *)fb2);

    return 0;
}
```

Because b.get() != fb2, so it should crash when the program exit? Or it is safe ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `shared_ptr<base>` can safely take ownership of a `derived*`, even if `base` does not have a virtual destructor.

However, this only works if `shared_ptr` knows what the most derived type of the object is when it takes ownership of it.  If you were to remove the casts

```
fooptr f(fb1);
fooptr b(fb2);
```

then you'd definitely be okay.  With the casts, the `shared_ptr` cannot know what the most-derived type of the object is when it takes ownership of it, so the behavior is undefined, just as if you had said:

```
foo* f = new foobar();
delete f;
```

The best thing to do is to follow the rule that ["a base class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and nonvirtual."](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm)

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not safe. `foo` and `bar` need virtual destructors, otherwise it's undefined what happens when the destructor of `shared_ptr` deletes the pointer it's holding. Of course, saying that it's not safe isn't the same as saying it should crash.

Alternatively, there's some magic[*] built into `shared_ptr` which means that if you don't cast to `foo*`, your code becomes safe:

```
fooptr f(fb1);
barptr b(fb2);
```

Either with the virtual destructor, or if you take out the casts, when shared_ptr comes to delete the pointer, the compiler will "know" how to adjust the pointer back to its original type, in order to call the correct destructors and free the memory.

The magic only works because `fb1` is type `foobar*`, though. Without the virtual destructor, the following is still unsafe:

```
foo *fb = new foobar();
fooptr f(fb);
```

If you use `shared_ptr` like this, then there's no risk of doing that:

```
fooptr f(new foobar());
```

You can also avoid the problem that in your code, that if the second call to `new foobar()` throws an exception, the first object is leaked. If you're going to use `shared_ptr` to manage memory for you, then you need to get the memory under management as quickly as possible:

```
fooptr f(new foobar());
barptr b(new foobar());
```

Now if the second line throws, `f` will be properly destructed and will delete the object.

[*] "magic" = a constructor template, which stores in the `shared_ptr` a pointer to a function which will cast the stored pointer back to the correct type, and then delete it.

Comment: if foo and bar both has virtual destructor, than it is safe?

Comment: Take the explicit cast off, though, and it is safe because `shared_ptr` has a templated constructor which ensures destruction through the type of the pointer originally passed to the constructor, not the template argument of the `shared_ptr` that eventually causes the final destruction. It's still highly advisable to have a virtual destructor in the base classes; but it's not technically dangerous.

Comment: I think that in destructor of shared_ptr, there should be "delete ptr", and the operation of delete do: 1) call the desturctor of the object, and 2) free the memory. But if the memory allcoated is 0x10000, but what the shared_ptr get is 0x10004, there shoud be some problem?

Comment: @Charles: yep, I'll get there. One thing at a time ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Just thought I'd point it out :) .  @doudehou: Having a virtual destructor is what the programmer uses to tell the compiler to insert any magic it needs to make it safe to delete a object via a pointer to base class. If the programmer doesn't do this the compiler is free to omit any checking and assume that the object pointed to is a base class instance, and only a base class isntance. What actually happens will vary from implementation to implementation as nothing is guaranteed (_undefined behaviour_). Typically, some destructor calls get omitted, but a memory error may also occur.

Comment: Further to what @Charles says, this case with multiple inheritance is a good one for causing a memory error. As @doudehou has spotted, converting between pointer types actually changes the address for (at least) one of the base classes. So any attempt to treat that address as the raw memory allocation is liable to fail.

Answer (score 0):

`foo` and `bar` aren't polymorphic classes and therefore this code will most likely result in invalid pointer deallocation.

Answer (score -1):

It is not safe since you are using a C-Style cast in a C++ code.

Do NOT use C-Style cast, use casts such as `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`.
Plus, no crash does not mean safety.

In fact, just remove the casts in this case.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is spelled `dynamic_cast`, period.